# Need help on integrating a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there any way of integrating this trigonometric function $$\int \cos(x^2)dx$$ ? Wolfram alpha straight away gives this $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}C\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x\right )+\text{constant}$$ without showing any steps.

It would be very helpful if someone could show the steps for me please..

Thank You

Comment: There are no steps to show -- $\int \cos(x^2)dx$ is the _definition_ of the [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) $C(x)$. The $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ factors must be due to differing scaling conventions.

Comment: @Henning: Yes indeed; the Fresnel integrals find use in optics (as part of the definition of the Cornu spiral among other things), and the scaling convention chosen simplifies the form of the applicable optical formulae...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed answer removed by author due to remarks below and to preserve the comments. Thanks for your comments. I should use glasses.

Comment: I think you're confusing $\sin(x^2)$ and $(\sin x)^2$.

Comment: You have it wrong; what you put in there is another Fresnel integral (the one that is usually paired with the OP's Fresnel integral).

Comment: Please tell me the difference between sin(x^2) and (sinx)^2

Comment: sin(x^2) = sin(x*x) - However, (sinx)^2 = sin(x)*Sin(x) - The two curves are totally different. When you have a function you can't distribute it unless it supports this feature. So it is NOT generally true to say that f(x*x)=f(x).f(x) - One function that supports this is f(x)=1.

Answer (score 2):

This integral $\int{\cos{(x^2)}dx}$ cannot be expressed by so called elementary functions.
Here is a link about similar integrals: http://www.math.unt.edu/integration_bee/AwfulTruth.html

Sincerely,

Tigran